# Padrino/Sinatra Rack-Test POST does not fill in params

Tags: ruby, rack, padrino, rack-test

I'm trying to use Rack-Test to issue a post request to my padrino app:

```
post '/sms', "name" => "Bryan"
```

My route looks like this:

```
post :index do
  puts params.inspect
  puts rack_input.inspect
end
```

`rack_input` is a method I wrote to parse the raw rack input. When I run the test, I get this output:

```
{}
"name=Bryan"
```

However, when I use curl on the command line, it works fine:

```
curl -d "name=Bryan" localhost:8080/sms

{"name"=>"Bryan"}
"name=Bryan"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm getting the same problem, any insights?

Comment: Same issue here. Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Try with symbols:

```
post '/sms', :name => "Bryan"
```

Comment: I did, it makes no difference.